# How to get many values into and out of a dialog box using PyQt

Tags: model-view-controller, dialog, pyqt

I have a portable app with a complex dialog box that shows the user tabs with many (over 50) different settings values that can be changed. The user can set the values and then either press OK or Cancel.

If the user presses OK, I want the app to store the changes in the model, but if the user presses Cancel, I want the app to forget any changes that were made.

What's the best strategy for getting values into and out of the dialog?

I know how to use  QDataWidgetMapper to map the model directly to widgets, but then I have an issue if the user clicks Cancel - I would have to undo all the changes made. On the other hand, if I create a dialog-specific object that stores values separately from the model, I then have to copy all the values from the model into the object and then copy them out again if the user presses OK. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QDataWidgetMapper`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatawidgetmapper.html) is ideal for this situation and it has two [submit policies](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatawidgetmapper.html#submitPolicy-prop). `AutoSubmit` and `ManualSubmit`. In your case, you can use the `ManualSubmit` and explicitly call `submit()` when the user presses `OK` or not submit at all when the user presses `Cancel`.